# How can I retry a parameterized test on JUnit 5?

Tags: junit

I have a flaky parameterized test that I want to retry a couple of times if it fails before actually saying fail when the test runs. There is good reason for the flakiness (it has to do with concurrency and small chance race conditions which does not overall affect the system) so no I don't need to remove the flakiness.

In JUnit 4 we could set up rules in which I set up a sort of "Retry rule" that retries the test x number of times before failing. However, in JUnit 5 that's gone and the only solutions I've seen so far involve normal JUnit 5 tests and not parameterized tests. What's the best way to retry a parameterized test in JUnit 5?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78035461/how-to-replace-parameterizedtest-with-retryingtest

Answer (score 0):

you can use junit-pioneer library for retrying

- normal test
- ParameterizedTest

if you are using maven:
you can specify this in your pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit-pioneer</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-pioneer</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and for your ParameterizedTest, you can add the extra @RetryingTest(3) annotation on top of your existing @ParameterizedTest annotation like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("foobarSource")
@RetryingTest(3)
void yourFlakyParameterizedTest(){

}
```

and for normal test you can replace @Test with @RetryingTest(3)

```
@RetryingTest(3)
void yourFlakyNormalTest() {
}
```

while 3 is the number of attempts you wish to retry upon failure attempts, and you can change it to different number that you specified

https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/retrying-test/

Comment: Sadly, this does not work. `@ParameterizedTest` and `@RetryingTest` are both evaluated separately, so that the test will be run once for each parameter and n times with the error, that no parameter resolver is specified for the retrying test annotation (see https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/retrying-test/#combining-retryingtest-with-test-et-al).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you expect can be achieved using `@ParameterizedRepeatedIfExceptionsTest` from [rerunner-jupiter](https://github.com/artsok/rerunner-jupiter) extension. Though the extension's readme says Java 8 is required, the core functionality(parameters and repeat) did work fine when I tested in Java 17.

**Dependency:** (gradle)

```
testImplementation group: 'io.github.artsok', name: 'rerunner-jupiter', version: '2.1.6'
```

**Sample test:**

```java
package io.github.devatherock.util;

import io.github.artsok.ParameterizedRepeatedIfExceptionsTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestUtilTest {
    private static int errorCounter = 0;
    private static int resultIndex = 0;
    private static List<Integer> args = Arrays.asList(14, 15, 100, -10);

    @ParameterizedRepeatedIfExceptionsTest(repeats = 3)
    @ValueSource(ints = {14, 15, 100, -10})
    public void testRepeat(int argument) {
        if ((argument == 14 || argument == -10) && errorCounter++ < 2) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Testing repeat");
        }
        errorCounter = 0;
        Assertions.assertEquals(args.get(resultIndex++), argument);
    }
}
```

The test is written to accept 4 inputs and fail twice for the first and last inputs. In total, the test will be executed 8 times - thrice each for the first and last inputs, once each for the second and third inputs. Test logs from gradle below:

```
TestUtilTest > testRepeat(int) > io.github.devatherock.util.TestUtilTest.testRepeat(int)[1] SKIPPED

TestUtilTest > testRepeat(int) > io.github.devatherock.util.TestUtilTest.testRepeat(int)[2] SKIPPED

TestUtilTest > testRepeat(int) > io.github.devatherock.util.TestUtilTest.testRepeat(int)[3] PASSED

TestUtilTest > testRepeat(int) > io.github.devatherock.util.TestUtilTest.testRepeat(int)[4] PASSED

TestUtilTest > testRepeat(int) > io.github.devatherock.util.TestUtilTest.testRepeat(int)[5] PASSED

TestUtilTest > testRepeat(int) > io.github.devatherock.util.TestUtilTest.testRepeat(int)[6] SKIPPED

TestUtilTest > testRepeat(int) > io.github.devatherock.util.TestUtilTest.testRepeat(int)[7] SKIPPED

TestUtilTest > testRepeat(int) > io.github.devatherock.util.TestUtilTest.testRepeat(int)[8] PASSED
```